# Как можно создать эффект "печатающегося" текста по таймеру?

Tags: delphi

Как можно создать эффект "печатающегося" текста по таймеру?
Вопрос, как бы, "печатается", увеличиваясь на одну букву. Компонент-Tmemo

Comment: В каком компоненте надо такое реализовать? В TImage, TMemo, где?

Comment: В компоненте TMemo

Answer (score 7):

Руками, все руками...

Идея простая. Вешаешь на таймер обработчик, в каждой итерации которого к тексту в TMemo добавляешь один символ из строки которая должна получиться. Когда строка закончилась останавливаешь таймер.

Код писать не буду. Для того кто хочет разобраться это лишнее.

Comment: Во-во, не нужно такой до ужаса простой код писать. Кстати, вопрос, 

похоже, вытекает из одного из моих ответов.

Answer (score 0):

Неужели это правда так трудно: создать эффект печатающегося текста в простейшем в использовании компоненте?

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);  // событие "OnTimer"
begin
memo1.Lines.Text:=memo1.Lines.Text+CHR(Random(254)+40);  // печатаем...
end;
```

Поставьте интервал таймера в пределах от 100 до 600 мс

Comment: 600 много, я когда-то проверял на программе выводящей графики - полсекунды и человек начинает думать что прога зависла